# i need to change the image when return null to temp image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im loading an image path from DB and and i want to handle if null picture to show temp image, im using the following code, and unfortunately its not working,
 can anyone fix this or provide me with a new solution  ?

```
echo ' <img src=" '. $row['log_image'] .' " id="logImage"/>';
```

and the script to handle the temp image

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var logSrc = $('#logImage').attr('src');
    if (logSrc == null || logSrc == "") {
        $('#logImage').attr('src', '/images/temp_logbook.JPG');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not handle the eror on server side like in this example [link](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php#refsect1-function.file-exists-examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `error` event gets raised on an `img` element when the `src` is invalid, or cannot be loaded. You can then hook to that element and change the `src` to your temp version, like this:

```
$('#logImage').on('error', function() {
    $(this).prop('src', '/images/temp_logbook.JPG');
});
```

Note jQuery v3 removed the `error()` method, so you need to use `on('error', fn)` as above.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3zqu0xtc/)

Comment: unfortunately when i remove the image from the directory, the server reply with 404 and still the temp image didn't show.

Comment: Do you have multiple `#logImage` elements in the DOM?

Comment: You're right, my bad. `error()` is removed in jQuery 3.0, you need to use `on('error', fn)`. I updated my answer for you

Comment: i need more reputation to vote up, thank you for assistant. will vote up when i can :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the length of the src

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       if (#logImage.src.length <1 ) {
            $('#logImage').attr('src', '/images/temp_logbook.JPG');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use only PHP, like that :

```
echo ' <img src=" '. (($row['log_image'] != null && $row['log_image'] != '') $row['log_image'] : '/images/temp_logbook.JPG') .' " id="logImage"/>';
```